# What's the default hibernate session control behavior in spring?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, session

I have a 3 layer application using spring and hibernate (controller -> service -> dao) and transaction is applied to service layer. I don't configure OpenSessionInViewInterceptor or OpenSessionInViewFilter and I want to know the hibernate session control behavior. Open session per transaction or per request? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the [`HibernateTransactionManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTransactionManager.html), a `Session` will get bound to the current thread and flushed and closed when the transaction ends, either through commit or roll back.

#### See also

- [10. Transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

Comment: so a session per transaction?

Comment: Thanks, Pascal! Another question, if one controller calls two different service method (they are in different transactions but in only one thread), there should be two sessions opened. Am I right?

Comment: @stinghu provided that the controller method is not marked `@Transactional` itself, that is.