# Hibernate - 2nd Transaction in same Session doesn't save modified object

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

OK, so my problem is I perform a 2nd transaction in the same session, it appears that any modified object as part of that 2nd transaction isn't saved by session.save().  I've compared the run of the 1st transaction and notice that none of the objects referenced during the 2nd are in the Persistence Context.  Here's the 1st transaction:

```
197459 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG com.microstar.tap2.processors.ShipmentProcessor  - Saving updated shipment!
197476 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager  - Initiating transaction commit
197476 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager  - Committing Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.microstar.tap2.datamodel.tap.User#23896], EntityKey[com.microstar.tap2.datamodel.tap.Shipment#778901], EntityKey[com.microstar.tap2.datamodel.tap.User#22268], EntityKey[com.microstar.tap2.datamodel.tap.User#19991
```

Where the 2nd transaction shows this:

```
402754 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.microstar.tap2.processors.ShipmentProcessor  - Saving updated shipment!
402754 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager  - Initiating transaction commit
402754 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager  - Committing Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@57573be6 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1255bf68
```

My code execution is identical for both transactions... I've stepped through it many times.  It's the same exact method that gets executed for two different rows in the same table of the same database.  This is running Java 8 in AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Tomcat8) - but also happens running on Java8 from within Eclipse/Tomcat8.

This app is a REST API.  Here's the resource definition:

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/quote", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

That method does nothing directly with sessions/hibernate.  But it calls DAOs that do.  The first thing that all resource controllers do is check authentication/authorization:

```
String tapUserId = authUtil.checkAuthorization(...)
```

This in turn calls a DAO and the base class for all DAOs has a method:

```
Session getSession()
{
    if (session == null)
    {
        try
        {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            logger.debug("Got current session: " + session);
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.debug("NO current session!");
        }
    }
    if (session == null)
    {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        logger.debug("Opened new session: " + session);
    }
    if ( session != null && !session.isOpen() )
    {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        logger.debug("Had to re-open session: " + session);
    }

    return session;
}
```

The next thing it does is fetch the shipment using Hibernate:

```
    logger.debug("Using orderId: " + orderId);
    session = getSession();
    Query query = session.getNamedQuery(Shipment.SHIPMENT_FINDBY_ORDERID_ID); 
    query.setString("orderid", orderId);
    Object r = query.uniqueResult();
    if ( r == null )
        return null;

    return (Shipment)r;
```

The log for the 2nd transaction shows the debug message "Got current session" and dumping the session shows that the entityKeys array within the PersistenceContext is empty - but I'd expect that at that point.  Whereas in the 1st transaction, the log entry is "Opened new Session" - again with empty entityKeys array.

The last functional line of the controller for the resource calls the DAO to update the record which in turn does this:

```
    session = getSession();
    session.save(shipment);
    return shipment;
```

I'm totally lost as to why this is even an issue, but I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with my Session/Transaction management.  The resources, as shown above are all using @Transaction - no modifiers.

So, what am I missing?

Thanks,
-Mac

Comment: What happens if you use session.persist(shipment)?

Comment: @Argb32: Unfortunately, the same exact behavior.  Thanks for the try though!

Comment: As you trying to save an updated version of existing entity it's better to use update() or merge():
    return session.merge(shipment);

Comment: @Argb32 Yes, exactly.  merge() and update() have same behavior as save() unfortunately.

Comment: Your getSession method looks weird for me. Do you keep the hibernate session in member or static variable in your DAO? You shall not do that. Second, how could it happen that the getCurrentSession does not return current session? This shall never be the case, either. How comes the session factory into your DAO?

Comment: I personally would go for JPA and insert EntityManager with @PersistentContext. But if you have to go with Hibernate API, make sure that you inject the session factory and always use the sessionFactory.getCurrentSession. You shall never ever do your own session bookeeping between the invocations as this is what are you using Spring for.

Comment: In another words - one transaction = one session.

Comment: And that was it!  Thanks so much @Michal!  I guess when I was writing the class, I just thought why not keep the session around.. just trying to be efficient I guess.

Comment: I have written that up as an answer including links to docs which - or at least I hope so - clarifies the issues further. If you found/find either the comment or the answer helpfull, I would be glad if you accepted the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Michal, the problem is solved.  In my base DAO class, I had the session as an instance variable, which screwed things up.  Not entirely sure why exactly, but I also agree that one transaction = one session.

So the solution was to make the session a method variable and basically always ask the session factory for the session.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight), spring defaults to *one Hibernate Session per transaction*.

In order for your setup to work you also need to:

- let spring inject the `SessionFactory` instance
- as soon as you leave (or enter new) transactional boundaries (demarked by `@Transactional`) retrieve new Hibernate `Session` by `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`

Caching `SessionFactory` and/or `Session` instances in application code hinders the framework on his task to manage the transactions correctly. The framework cannot know which `Session` the application code decides to use. Therefore the framework requires the application code to take the session the framework prepared and stored for retrieval per `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`. On that `Session` the framework performs then the session and transaction live cycle management.

I also find this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921197/whats-the-default-hibernate-session-control-behavior-in-spring) and this [Hibernate Documentation](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions) helpful.